# How to add a dynamic scroll view in onClick

Tags: java, android

I created a table row that if I click the grid item it shows this table row and I need this table row Scrollable.

I want to add a dynamic scroll view in this code in table row, but it crashed when I use the `onclick`, Could any one help me for this error is

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

```
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Result tr
                TableRow tr_head2 = new TableRow(GridDynamic.this);
                tr_head2.setId(10);
                tr_head2.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fab_label_background));
                tr_head2.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                tr_head2.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

                TextView label_category2 = new TextView(GridDynamic.this);
                label_category2.setId(20);
                label_category2.setText("1");
                label_category2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                label_category2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                label_category2.setTextSize(18);
                label_category2.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3);
                tr_head2.addView(label_category2);// add the column to the table row here

                TextView label_quantity_amount2 = new TextView(GridDynamic.this);
                label_quantity_amount2.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
                label_quantity_amount2.setText(alphabets.get(arg2).get("Name").toString()); // set the text for the header
                label_quantity_amount2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                label_quantity_amount2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                label_quantity_amount2.setTextSize(18);
                label_quantity_amount2.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3); // set the padding (if required)
                tr_head2.addView(label_quantity_amount2); // add the column to the table row here

                TextView label_total_price_amount2 = new TextView(GridDynamic.this);
                label_total_price_amount2.setId(22);// define id that must be unique
                label_total_price_amount2.setText(alphabets.get(arg2).get("Price").toString()); // set the text for the header
                label_total_price_amount2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // set the color
                label_total_price_amount2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                label_total_price_amount2.setTextSize(18);
                label_total_price_amount2.setPadding(20, 3, 20, 3); // set the padding (if required)
                tr_head2.addView(label_total_price_amount2); // add the column to the table row here

                tableLayout.addView(tr_head2, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(GridDynamic.this);
                scroll.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                scroll.addView(tr_head2);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), alphabets.get(arg2).get("Item_ID").toString()+
                                " "+alphabets.get(arg2).get("Name").toString()+
                        " "+alphabets.get(arg2).get("Price").toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are two `addView` in your code with the same parameter `tr_head2`, which may be the reason.